# Firebase Cloud Messaging topics stopped working

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

My devices stopped receiving silent push notifications in the background with topics, but I am able to send an FCM request from the command line to trigger a silent push notification in the background using an FCM Token instead of topics. My code for subscribing to topics and sending notifications with topics hasn't changed since before this broke (the last successful one I know about was on 12/31/19 - maybe something to do with the year switchover?). I did switch from using APNS certs to keys, but I don't know if that could be causing a problem with FCM topics.

Because this works with an FCM Token and not topics I think this is just a Firebase issue, not an app or Apple configuration issue, right?

How can I debug this to get it working? Firebase Cloud Messaging seems to be a black box...

Comment: If there is an outage in the delivery of messages to FCM topics, that would be posted [Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/). It currently doesn't show any such outage, but since the status page is reactive it can sometimes take some time before it shows outages. If you think there's an outage that is not reported there yet, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. In either case, there's nothing anyone here can do about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be reported to Firebase support as a possible service outage.

Comment: This has been going on for the last few weeks, so I expect any Firebase service outage would have been noticed and fixed by now. And I have been in touch with Firebase support, but I'm afraid that's stalled - that's why I'm trying to figure out if/how to debug this myself.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If you want to submit an answer saying it's a Firebase issue and not debuggable on my end, I'll mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to say whether this is a problem with Firebase Cloud Messaging based on the information in the question. But if *you* think it's an outage, you should report it to Firebase support. If you want our help on determining whether maybe it's a problem in your implementation, provide the [minimal code/steps with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase support first pointed me at this [debugging guide](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html); I suspect this is their first line of advice when people are having trouble with notifications.

For me, the issue was around topics, and here's how I tackled it:

1. I tried to subscribe a device using its FCM Token from my server - after doing that it responded to this topic, so I knew the problem was with the device subscribing itself.
2. The Swift topic subscribe/unsubscribe calls are actually async, which I didn't realize, but after I supplied completion handlers I could tell they weren't working, which led to my solution.